# What all is required to completely uninstall Webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, installation

After disabling and uninstalling Webform, I noticed that it appears to still be active. Existing Webform content are all still there and accessible. [Apparently this is intended behavior](https://www.drupal.org/node/1913500).

I can delete the content and content type, but I'm worried there might be other items or residue that is not as apparent. **What all do I need to do in order to completely remove all Webform stuff from the site?**

Comment: Did you delete its folder from /sites/all/modules ? 

There is no problem you can delete its content type. if you are really worry about other contents just back up of your website

Comment: I'm just wondering if there are any other pieces Webform left behind.

Comment: Drupal is totally modular, a module is a component of a system. if you delete the folder nothing will be left

Comment: @Drupalist um, you uninstall and delete the folder and the content is literally still there. I'm getting more confused...

Answer (score 1):

Like I said you need to uninstall it from `/modules` UI and then delete its folder from `/site/all/modules`.

If you take a look at webform module source code, in `webform.install` under `function webform_uninstall()` you will find this code:

```
foreach (node_type_get_names() as $type => $name) {
    variable_del('webform_node_' . $type);
}
```

as you can see it deletes every node which has webform type. for more details of what is going to be deleted after uninstalling the module, check the  `function webform_install()` and `function webform_uninstall()` functions in the mentioned file.